# Command dpkg upgrade on fedora-like so

Tags: fedora, deb, dpkg

I'm trying install .deb files in fedora and its dosn't work like using apt
to command sudo apt install upgrade (debian-like upgrade command)

i'd like to know how upgrade dpkg command in fedora

idk how is it works on fedora

Answer (score 1):

Fedora does not use `.deb` packages, or dpkg or apt. Apt is actually *available*, but it's there as a cross-distro compatibility tool.

Instead, you should use `dnf`, a tool that is similar to apt and works with the `.rpm` packages Fedora Linux is built from.

See [APT command equivalents on Fedora with DNF](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/dnf-vs-apt/) for a quick cheat-sheet for DNF for people who are used to Apt.

Note that some package names may be different, as well, as Fedora and Debian have different naming conventions.